# Assigning current 'User' as foreign key to nested serializers

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to assign current 'User' to two models using nested serializers.

```
class UserAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ('user', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'country',
                  'state_province', 'city', 'zip_code')


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_address = UserAddressSerializer()
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name',
                  'title', 'display_name', 'time_zone', 'user_address', 'default_office')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_address_data = validated_data.pop('user_address')
        user_address_object = UserAddress.objects.create(
            user=user, **user_address_data)
        user_profile_object = UserProfile.objects.create(
            user=user, **validated_data)

        return user
```

What I am getting is this output in Postman.

```
{
    "user_address": {
        "user": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to know a way to pass 'User' to both of these model creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `user` from fields of `UserAddressSerializer`:

```
class UserAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ('address_1', 'address_2', 'country',  # <-- Here
                  'state_province', 'city', 'zip_code')
```